# Groups with only one maximal abelian subgroup

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, maximal-subgroup

I've just proven that every Group has an abelian Subgroup $A$ such that $A < B \leq G \rightarrow B$ is nonabelian using Zorn's Lemma. Heres a sketch of said proof: Let $\Omega$ be the set of abelian subgroups of G(this set is obviously partially ordered by inclusion and nonempty as it contains the trivial subgroup) and $I_0\subseteq I_1 \subseteq ...$ a chain in $\Omega$. Then $\bigcup_{i \in \mathbb{N}} I_i$ is a supremum of said chain in $\Omega$. By Zorn's Lemma $\Omega$ must contain maximal Elements.

Now I'm trying to characterize Groups that have only one such maximal subgroup. But I don't really see the property of a Group that makes it have only a single such subgroup.

Comment: Let's see the proof, then.

Comment: I guess I worded this sloppily, I've proven that every Group has an abelian Subgroup $A$ such that $A < B \leq G \rightarrow B$ is not abelian. The proof is pretty standard stuff, take the Union of a chain of abelian subgroups and so on.

Comment: I suggest that you share the entire proof, standard or not. Please [edit] your question accordingly.

Comment: Let $\Omega$ be the set of abelian subgroups of $G$(this set is obviously partially ordered by inclusion) and $I_0 \subseteq I_1 \subset ...$ a chain in $\Omega$. Then $\cup_{i \in \mathbb{N}} I_i$ is a supremum of said chain in $\Omega$. By Zorn's Lemma $\Omega$ must contain maximal Elements.

Comment: If $G$ is abelian then so is $B$.

Comment: Is there actually a question here? It would be nice to state it explicitly. You'll know when you're done, because your question will end with a question-mark. :)

Comment: @CyclotomicField If $G$ is abelian then $A = G$ and we want $A$ to be a real subset of $B$. You're right that abelian Groups statisfy the property but I believe there are weaker prerequisites.

Comment: @user844177 that's not true. Consider $\mathbb{Z}^2$. There is a proper abelian subgroup generated by $(1,0)$ that is isomorphic to $\mathbb{Z}$.

Comment: @JohnHughes My question is which groups have only a single abelian subgroup that is maximal in the way described above?

Comment: @CyclotomicField But $<(1,0)>$ is not maximal in the set of abelian subroups of $\mathbb{Z}^2$ as $<(1,0)> \subset \mathbb{Z}^2$

Comment: @user844177 as John Hughes pointed out there isn't any question asked here and the first sentence sentence is clearly false. You'll need to restate the problem and ask a question.

Comment: @CyclotomicField I don't believe the first sentence is false, and my question  was just answered

Comment: Yes, the first sentence is correct, but I am afraid it is not true that your question was answered, because you didn't ask a question :)

Comment: @DerekHolt lets not get too pedantic. Just because a sentence doesn't end with a question mark doesn't mean there is no question. And it is fairly easy to understand what's being asked here, given a bit of good will.

Comment: @freakish Sorry I was being facetious - note the smilie!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Only abelian groups have one maximal abelian subgroup.

Assume that $H$ is a maximal abelian subgroup of a nonabelian group $G$. Pick any $x\not\in H$ (which exists since $H\neq G$). Then $\langle x\rangle$ is abelian and thus contained in some maximal abelian subgroup $H'$. Obviously $H$ and $H'$ cannot be equal.

Comment: Why must every abelian subgroup be contained in some maximal abelian subgroup? I can see the proof via another application of Zorn's lemma, namely taking $\Omega$ to be all those abelian subgroups containing $x$ but not sure if there's some direct way to conclude that by already using the result that OP has proven. (In the case of commutative rings with $1$, one can quotient and conclude that every ideal is contained in a maximal one but here $\langle x \rangle$ needn't be normal.)

Comment: @AryamanMaithani I don't think that OP's result can be applied here directly. Indeed, you have to consider all subgroups containing $\langle x\rangle$ and apply Zorn's lemma one more time. I don't see another way.

Comment: Note that OP's result can be generalized to both cases by considering all abelian subgroups containing an abelian subset $A$ (meaning $a,b\in A$ implies $ab=ba$, not necessarily a subgroup). Then OP's result is for $A=\{e\}$ while the one I've used for $A=\{x\}$.

Comment: Ah, I was thinking of generalising it by considering abelian subgroups, in which case OP's result is for $\{1\}$. I believe it's about the same because to claim that $\Omega$ is non-empty, I guess you would claim that $\langle A \rangle$ is an abelian subgroup which is in $\Omega$?

Comment: If $A$ is an abelian subset then $\langle A\rangle$ indeed is an abelian subgroup. But yeah, you are right: we can restrict ourselves to abelian subgroups only.